# Implication of complete measure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a complete measure on $(X, \mathbb U)$. Show for all $A,N \in \mathbb U$

$$ \mu(A) \gt0=\mu(N) \Longrightarrow \mu(A \cap N^c) \gt 0$$

My Idea:

**Case 1:** $A \cap N = \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow \mu(A\cap N^c) = \mu(A) \gt 0$

**Case 2:** $A \cap N \neq \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow \mu(A \cap N^c) = \mu(A$\ $N) = \mu(A) - \mu(N) = \mu(A) \gt 0$

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do $$\mu(A\cap N^c)=\mu(A\cap N^c)+\mu(A\cap N)=\mu((A\cap N^c)\cup(A\cap N))=\mu(A)>0$$

The first equality is due to $A\cap N\subset N$, $\mu(N)=0$, and $\mu$ being complete giving you that $\mu(A\cap N)=0$.

Note: In your case 2, for the second equality, while true given the hypotheses, the argument in your head might not be correct. I would double check it.

Comment: That is really neat thank you